# spring MVC WebApp with quartz job scheduler

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am doing a Web app with spring mvc and I need to develop a proces that must be executed every night. To do it I decided to use the library Quartz, but  I have doubts on the implementation.

What is the best approach?

Integrate the process in the project or develop a total different app that will execute the job.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose i suggest you to use Spring @Scheduled annotation.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {
 //TO DO
}
```

In this example, you are scheduling a task to be executed at 10:15 AM on the 15th day of every month.